# Unpivot, pivot and Count values in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[image: I've got a table that looks something like this]

I'm trying to count all the different answerTypes while doing a pivot & unpivot to get the QuestionNumber as distinct row values.

[image: The end result looking like this]

I can't figure out how to combine all this into a single query in BigQuery to get that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is:

```
select question,
       countif(q = 'Good') as good,
       countif(q = 'Bad') as bad,
       countif(q = 'N/A') as n_a
from ((select '1A' as question, question1a  as q from t) union all
      (select '1B' as question, question1b from t) union all
      (select '1C' as question, question1c from t)
     ) x
group by question;
```

There are fancier ways to unpivot the data, but this seems to capture what you want to do.